# How to create a custom command prompt in python

Tags: python, command-line-interface

We have a CLI tool which uses Typer module in python.

However, I want to create a custom command prompt - like the mysql prompt for example.

```
mysql>
```

Currently, the commands are invoked like:

```
C:\Users\ABC> python wowcli.py command1 paramA paramB
C:\Users\ABC> python wowcli.py command2 paramC paramD
```

I am trying to achieve something like:

```
C:\Users\ABC> python wowcli.py
wowcli> command1 paramA paramB
wowcli> command2 paramC paramD
```

Is there any python library that we can install or otherwise? Please suggest.

Comment: Does rich satisfy your need? https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html

Comment: @YaakovBressler Thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure if rick have the functionality I am looking for. I have now edited the question to add context. Please have a check.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to build a custom REPL, read evaluate print loop.

Your question is very broad but you can get started here https://dev.to/amal/building-the-python-repl-3468

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure what you mean here. Have a look at [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). You can "parse" these arguments with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 0):

I Made A Script That Can Dynamically Add Commands To The App, Bind A Function To It And Give It All The Args Of The Command As Its First Parameter,

```
import time
import os

class Data:
    init = 0
    cmd = ""
    ss = "$"
    commands = {}
    default = []
    temp = {"0":[]}
    startup = [False, "", ""]
    error = True
    bucket = []
    alrt = ""
    wait = 0

class File:
    def read(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            return f.read()

    def write(self, filename, contents):
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(contents)
        return 1

class Shell:
    def clear(self):
        os.system("cls")

    def run(self, command):
        if Shell != "":
            try:
                Data.commands[command[0]]
            except:
                print("Invalid Command")

    def start(self):
        if Data.alrt != "":
            print(Data.alrt)
            Data.alrt = ""

        time.sleep(Data.wait)
        Data.wait = 0

        cmd = input(Data.ss + " ")
        self.run(cmd.split(" "))
        self.start()

    def symbol(self, symbol: str):
        Data.ss = symbol

    def new(self, command, function):
        Data.commands.update({command: [function]})

    def delete(self, command):
        del Data.commands[command]

    def getcommands(self):
        return Data.commands

    def getcommand(self, command):
        return Data.commands[command]

    def reset(self):
        Data.commands = Data.default

    def show(self, parameters):
        print(" ".join(parameters[1:]))

    def startup(self, message, dialog):
        Data.startup[0] = True
        Data.startup[1] = message
        Data.startup[2] = dialog

    def alert(self, message):
        Data.alrt = message

    def wait(self, timeAmount):
        Data.wait = timeAmount

Data.default = Data.commands
```

It Is Under Development And The Startup Feature Does Not Work Yet But Everything Else Does.
Hope This Helps!